# Write to a file with a specific encoding in Java

Tags: java, encoding, utf-8, randomaccessfile, iso-8859-15

This *might* be related to my [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39262555/interpret-a-string-from-one-encoding-to-another-in-java/39262819?noredirect=1#comment65861448_39262819) (on how to convert "fÃ¶r"  to "för")

So I have a file that I create in my code. Right now I create it by the following code:

```
FileWriter fwOne = new FileWriter(wordIndexPath);
BufferedWriter wordIndex = new BufferedWriter(fwOne);
```

followed by a few

```
wordIndex.write(wordBuilder.toString()); //that's a StringBuilder
```

ending (after a while-loop) with a

```
wordIndex.close();
```

Now the problem is later on this file is huge and I want (need) to jump in it without going through the entire file. The `seek(long pos)` method of `RandomAccessFile` lets me do this.

**Here's my problem**: The characters in the file I've created seem to be encoded with UTF-8 and the only info I have when I seek is the character-position I want to jump to. `seek(long pos)` on the other hand jumps in bytes, so I don't end up in the right place since an UTF-8 character can be more than one byte.

**Here's my question**: Can I, when I write the file, write it in ISO-8859-15 instead (where a character is a byte)? That way the `seek(long pos)` will get me in the right position. Or should I instead try to use an alternative to `RandomAccessFile` (is there an alternative where you can jump to a character-position?)

Comment: You can make use FileOutputStream?

Comment: If a byte you read has a value less than 128, then it is the first byte in a UTF-8 character. A byte value of 128-255 is the middle of a sequence. You can seek randomly and then find the next byte with a value 0-127.

Comment: You can make use of FileOutputStream. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1001540/how-to-write-a-utf-8-file-with-java

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to deal with a very large text file?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4722743/how-to-deal-with-a-very-large-text-file)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Now first the worrisome. FileWriter and FileReader are old utility classes, that use the default platform settings on that computer. Run elsewhere that code will give a different file, will not be able to read a file from another spot.

ISO-8859-15 is a single byte encoding. But java holds text in Unicode, so it
can combine all scripts. And `char` is UTF-16. In general a char index will not be a byte index, but in your case it probably works. But the line break might be one `\n` or two `\r\n` chars/bytes - platform dependently.

Re

Personally I think UTF-8 is well established, and it is easier to use:

```
byte[] bytes = string.getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
string = new String(bytes, StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
```

That way all special quotes, euro, and so on will always be available.

At least specify the encoding:

```
Files.newBufferedWriter(file.toPath(), "ISO-8859-15");
```

Comment: Thanks so much for your answer. Here's a question though. If i go with the well esablished UTF-8, how would I solve searching through the file? (right now I can jump to a specific byte-position with RandomAccessFile.seek(long pos)

Comment: One could use a memory mapped ByteBuffer, go through that for exact file positions with a Charset.Decoder, and index those positions. So use a FileChannel with "r" (read-only mode) for indexing, That is relatively fast. Start with sample code.